# Receiving EnvCommandError when run poetry install on Apple M1 MacOs Monterey

Tags: python, apple-m1, python-poetry, macos-monterey

I'm facing the issue when running `poetry install` command in my new Macbook Pro using Apple M1 chip and MacOS Monterey. I tried many suggestions so far but still cannot make it fixed.
Python version: 3.8.12

```
>>> poetry install                     
Installing dependencies from lock file

Package operations: 20 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals

  • Installing scipy (1.6.0): Failed

  EnvCommandError

  Command ['/Users/<retacted>/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/reporting-executor-3zOoUFwf-py3.8/bin/pip', 'install', '--no-deps', 'file:///Users/<retacted>/Library/Caches/pypoetry/artifacts/e2/fc/a9/d781fc7053c9e0aa0b94b47220fee30ba4ef114e7d11b36b3cc68b1b95/scipy-1.6.0.tar.gz'] errored with the following return code 1, and output: 
  Processing /Users/<retacted>/Library/Caches/pypoetry/artifacts/e2/fc/a9/d781fc7053c9e0aa0b94b47220fee30ba4ef114e7d11b36b3cc68b1b95/scipy-1.6.0.tar.gz
    Installing build dependencies: started
    Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
    Getting requirements to build wheel: started
    Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
    Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
    Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Users/<retacted>/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/reporting-executor-3zOoUFwf-py3.8/bin/python /Users/<retacted>/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/reporting-executor-3zOoUFwf-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /var/folders/54/n12zwf1n74vg5knvnd37ph880000gp/T/tmpusexpj06
         cwd: /private/var/folders/54/n12zwf1n74vg5knvnd37ph880000gp/T/pip-req-build-xbw8rqq2
    Complete output (4 lines):
    setup.py:461: UserWarning: Unrecognized setuptools command ('dist_info --egg-base /private/var/folders/54/n12zwf1n74vg5knvnd37ph880000gp/T/pip-modern-metadata-1_oeqwwo'), proceeding with generating Cython sources and expanding templates
      warnings.warn("Unrecognized setuptools command ('{}'), proceeding with "
    Error: 'None' must be installed before running the build.
```

Here is what I tried:

- Running the terminal under Rosetta mode
- I can be able to install `scipy` via the command `arch -arm64 pip install scipy` without issue but the version is 1.7.3
- Tried `arch -arm64 pip install scipy==1.6.0` getting the error

```
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [4 lines of output]
      setup.py:461: UserWarning: Unrecognized setuptools command ('dist_info --egg-base /private/var/folders/54/n12zwf1n74vg5knvnd37ph880000gp/T/pip-modern-metadata-rsi6te2b'), proceeding with generating Cython sources and expanding templates
        warnings.warn("Unrecognized setuptools command ('{}'), proceeding with "
      Error: 'None' must be installed before running the build.
      
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
```

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar issue and it seems to be a Python version issue: https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/2629

We downgraded to Python 3.7 for example. Maybe try other versions that is still fine for your project.

Comment: Not sure why I cannot install 3.8.6 version
`
BUILD FAILED (OS X 12.0 using python-build 20180424)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/54/n12zwf1n74vg5knvnd37ph880000gp/T/python-build.20220204091905.15387
Results logged to /var/folders/54/n12zwf1n74vg5knvnd37ph880000gp/T/python-build.20220204091905.15387.log

checking whether pthread_key_t is compatible with int... no
configure: error: Unexpected output of 'arch' on OSX
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
`
pyenv can install 3.10.1 version

Comment: I got the same issue on python 3.10.1

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Have you tried installing with python 3.7? It seems like that version has the least package conflicts. Since 3.10 is quite new I expect it to have the most issues.

Comment: my application does require 3.8 version at least, thus I haven't tried 3.7 yet. trying 3.8 or above